# how to get item index or number along with key,value in dict

Tags: python

For dictionary I want to keep track of number of items that have been parsed. Is there a better way to do that compared to what is shown below?

```
count = 0
for key,value in my_dict.items():
     count += 1
     print key,value, count
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for count, (key, value) in enumerate(my_dict.items(), 1):
    print key, value, count
```

`enumerate()` efficiently adds a count to the iterator you are looping over. In the above example I tell `enumerate()` to start counting at `1` to match your example; the default is to start at 0.

Demo:

```
>>> somedict = {'foo': 'bar', 42: 'Life, the Universe and Everything', 'monty': 'python'}
>>> for count, (key, value) in enumerate(somedict.items(), 1):
...     print key, value, count
... 
42 Life, the Universe and Everything 1
foo bar 2
monty python 3
```